# Show as an alert instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have these lines in a script which I'd like to show as an alert instead:

```
mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
```

but the alert displays it as-is, what do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert($('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html());
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you well, but you might want to `alert` the text-contents from that element.
Would look like

```
alert(mce_jQuery('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').text());
```

Comment: Hmm..no alert displayed at all. I've edited the desc to include the following line as well

Comment: @Nimbux , with firebug can you see if you contents in that html , if so it has to print when you say .text() or html() , sometimes .text() doesn't show in ie depending on when you are calling that but .html() should show